# Adding Null Value To DATE Field In SQL SERVER

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a table that has a field that is a Date. It allows nulls.
I am trying to use a stored procedure to add a value to that field, but when I pass null, I get a

> "Stored Procedure expects a value for @ReadyDate."

Here is the stored procedure:

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_UpdateStatus]
@id int,
@status varchar(20),
@ReadyDate Date
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE PMF_ToolingRequests
        SET status = @status,
        ReadyDate = @ReadyDate
    WHERE ID = @id
END
```

Here is the C# code I am using to update the field. It balks when I send an empty string as well:

```
if (setReadyTime)
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ReadyDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
}
else
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ReadyDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = (DateTime?)null;
}

cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@status", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = status;
```

I also tried:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ReadyDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = null;
```

There is no value in that field at certain times. I would like to fill it in when the condition is met.

Comment: There are basically two ways to handle this and both of them have been presented as answers. Either of them will work, it just depends on how you want to handle it.

Comment: if one of these answers worked for you, please consider accepting it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

do

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ReadyDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = DBNull.Value;
```

in essence, `null` in an object oriented language has a slightly different meaning than `NULL` in your DB, which is why

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ReadyDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = null;
```

doesn't work.

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull(v=vs.110).aspx) is an MSDN article talking about DBNull if you want to do some reading.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

Pass `ReadyDate` with Default value as null

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_UpdateStatus]
@id int,
@status varchar(20),
@ReadyDate Date=null
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE PMF_ToolingRequests
        SET status = @status,
        ReadyDate = @ReadyDate
    WHERE ID = @id
END
```

Comment: that will work but imho is risky because this is the way to provide a default value for parameters and not a method to pass `null` values. the risk is to have bad calls with `null` just because a developer forgot to put a parameter in the declaration of a datasource and that mistake went unnoticed.